# Are there PyCharm themes?

Tags: ide, themes, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I don't ask for color schemes.
Are there any custom themes, is it even possible to create them?

> Options > Appearance > Themes

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE themes are Java look&feels. It's technically possible to install any third-party L&F into JVM (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) and use it in PyCharm, but it will most likely look ugly and break the UI in many places. If you decide to go this route, start with the Substance.